# Trying to stop thread, but it start again

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I'm using the next code to try to stop a thread, but when I see that Running is false it becomes true again.

```
public class usoos {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        end();
    }

    public static SimpleThreads start(){
        SimpleThreads id = new SimpleThreads();
        id.start();
        System.out.println("started.");
        return id;
    }

    public static void end(){
        System.out.println("finished.");
        start().shutdown();
    }
}
```

And the thread

```
public class SimpleThreads extends Thread {
    volatile boolean running = true;

    public SimpleThreads () {
    }

    public void run() {         
        while (running){
            System.out.println("Running = " + running);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down thread" + "======Running = " + running);
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        running = false;
        System.out.println("End" );
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to stop it(I set running to false), it starts again..

Answer (score 5):

Look at this line in the `end` method:

```
start().shutdown();
```

You are not stopping the original instance; you are starting another one, which you then immediately shut down.

There is no connection between your `start` and `end` methods—no information, no reference is passed from one to the other. It is obviously impossible to stop the thread you started in the `start` method.

Your `end` method should not be `static`; in fact, you don't even need it, `shutdown` is already it:

```
SimpleThreads t = start();
Thread.sleep(10000);
t.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the `end` method you just create a new `Thread` and kill it, save the thread instance and kill it:

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class usoos {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleThreads id = start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    end(id);
}

public static SimpleThreads start(){
    SimpleThreads id = new SimpleThreads();
    id.start();
    System.out.println("started.");
    return id;
}

public static void end(SimpleThreads id){
    System.out.println("finished.");
    id.shutdown();
}
```